# Informatica new column data loading into existing target table

Tags: etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter, iics

I have an requirement as there is one existing target table and now requirement is we have included one new column to it and the data to the target table should load from a new source table in new mapping, so how can I proceed with this requirement,kindly help

I tried taking target as lookup and some process but it's not working out, kindly give me ur valuable suggestions

Answer (score 0):

If your source extracts full data everyday, you dont have to do anything. But if its incremental, then you need to create a special mapping to update all/one newly created column( basically update historical data). You can follow below steps -

1. Use the target as source and target both. Choose PK and the newly added column and link to next.
2. Then add an expression transformation. Re-create the logic for the  newly added  column. If you need to join  or do a lookup to source or any other table, you can do it in this place.
3. Link newly added column and primary key to the target.
4. Mark the session as update only or  you can use update strategy.

Whole mapping will look like below -

```
TGT_SQ --> EXP...Other Trnfs... --> TGT
```

If both source and target are in same DB, you can use direct update as well.

Comment: Hi Koushik, Thanks for ur suggestion I have tried taking tgt as src and new src and done the joiner and linked to target but I am getting error as target table doesn't allow insert and i have changed target properties and checked sometimes I get cannot insert null values to pk column , I don't know what to do and how to proceed now, kindly help

Comment: i think then add an update strategy before target. And set it like this `IIF(NOT isnullPrimary_key), DD_UPDATE, DD_REJECT) ` to ensure only not null records will be updated.

Comment: Even though it's failing with same error

Comment: Pls check join type(outer or inner) in joiner ? This should be inner join. HOpe it will eliminate null PK.

Comment: It's inner join (normal join in informatica) and given above condition in update strategy also but same error