# In informatica Target has two primary keys one has duplicate rows but with other pk combined it will be unique

Tags: sql, etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter

In target there is data like

```
Rowid batchnum sold
1     10        Null
1      20       Null
```

Now the requirement is sold column is new column and we need to insert the data to sold column by taking target as a source and joining with other source, i tried below mapping flow

Tgt as src
New src.    --->joiner --->exp-->tgt

But all the rows are getting rejected and getting error like cannot insert null values into rowid or sometimes batchnum

Iam not able to figure out exact solution kindly help

Comment: A table can only have one primary key. A primary key can consist of one or several columns.

Comment: Add some more sample data, and also _specify_ the expected result.

Comment: Sample data will be similar to the one I shared, the expected output is for rowid 1 and batchnum 20(latest ) the sold column should update with data

Comment: A [mcve] is expected to include both. And also show us your current attempt. Make it easy to assist you!

Comment: I have taken tgt as src(s1) and joined with new src(s2) with have sold column and taken the two pk's from s1 and sold from s2 and linked to target but rows are getting rejected

Comment: I tried to answer to same question in this link- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77182090/informatica-new-column-data-loading-into-existing-target-table

Comment: Looking at your scenario, it seems source has some null values for Rowid or batchnum. Can you pls put a filter before  target with condition  `IIF ( NOT ISNULL(Rowid) AND NOT ISNULL( batchnum), TRUE, FALSE) = TRUE`